# Button - Change background color on click

Tags: android, xml, android-selector

I have 8 buttons in my activity. What I am looking for is, The buttons have a default background and when a button is clicked, the background color should change to some other color. This part is pretty straight forward. But, when I click on any other button, the background color of the first button should change back to default color. I understand that this will be done using "selector states", but I am not quite sure of how to implement it. The more i read about it, the more confused I am.

Right now, the xml that I have is as follows: in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/dark_grey" android:state_focused="true"/>  
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_border"/>

 </selector>
```

the drawable/image_border in the xml is used to define shape for the button. Below is the image_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="@color/dark_grey" />

    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="@color/light_grey" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

</shape>
```

Can someone help me with how to change the xml to behave the way I need it to be?

**[EDIT 1]**

All the below answers are pointing towards similar kind of solution. Here are the changes that I did. But, still, when i press the button, it turns to the specified color but immediately turns back to the default color.

button_background_blue.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_border_blue" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/dark_grey" android:state_focused="true"/>  
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_border"/>

 </selector>
```

image_border_blue.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="@color/blue" />

    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="@color/blue" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

</shape>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a shape named `button_pressed.xml`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="@color/blue" />

    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="@color/blue" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

</shape>
```

Suppose, you have two buttons whose IDs are `R.id.btn` and `R.id.btn1`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Press Me 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Press Me 2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Write the `onClick()` method which will allow you to retain the changed color until another button is pressed.

```
Button button;

public void onClick(View v) {

    Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_pressed);
    dr.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn:

        if (button == null) {
            button = (Button) findViewById(v.getId());
        } else {
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);
            button = (Button) findViewById(v.getId());
        }
        button.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);

        break;

    case R.id.btn2:
        if (button == null) {
            button = (Button) findViewById(v.getId());
        } else {
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);
            button = (Button) findViewById(v.getId());
        }
        button.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

I think, now you will get What you wanted to do.

Comment: I edited my question, can you have a look and suggest?

Comment: I tried your answer, but didn't work. The button background still goes back to original color.

Comment: did you replace your whole selector xml with this?

Comment: But it works for me 100%. Please, clean and build your project...then run again. then say, is it okay or not.

Comment: Here is what's happening. I click on the button, it changes to the color that i set, then immediately changing back to the color that was set to default.

Comment: see my latest updated solution...I think, this time you will get it right.

Comment: I just did the same type of solution. I will accept your answer. Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 17):

use this selector & put it in drawable folder & set button background to this selector.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/AliceBlue" android:state_focused="true"/>  
<item android:drawable="@color/Azure"/>

 </selector>
```

**OR**
You can use Color instead of Background.
hope it helps.

Comment: I used the same kind of xml, I removed comment for android:state_pressed in my question. But still it has the same effect.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, much simpler solution

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you this selector.

Just create a simple selector.xml file in drawable folder and then add the selector to your button as `android:background="@drawable/selector"` or by code like this: `yourButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selector));`

`selector.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/holo_purple" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/yourdrawable" />
</selector>
```

The first item is for `pressed`, the second for `focused` and the last is for `selected` state.

Answer (score 1):

changing background color in layout when respective color button is clicked in android

**main_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#b056ff"
    android:id="@+id/l1">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="RED"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="GREEN" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="BLUE"/>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
package ram.android.com.cwp1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

/**
 * Created by VENKATESH on 10-Jun-16.
 */
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    Button r, g, b;
    LinearLayout ll;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l1);
        r = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
        g = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);
        r.setOnClickListener(this);
        g.setOnClickListener(this);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.b1:
                ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                break;

            case R.id.b2:
                ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                break;
            case R.id.b3:
                ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                break;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thats too much brother

Comment: Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

I know it is very late but I hope some one would find useful.
I have very simple solution, I have used in my app and works awesome.

Let me explain the logic, 
 1. Keep track of 2 button clicks - previous button clicked and current button clicked. I am using ArrayList
 2. for every button click keep updating the previous and current button clicks value in ArrayList.
3. change the background color of previous button clicked.
4. change the background color of current button clicked.

I hope the logic is simple and straightforward.

Here is the implementation

xml

```
<Button
            android:onClick="onClickRosterDay"
            android:text="Mon"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorWhite"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:id="@+id/rosterMonday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

the OnClick method is defined for every button in XML, in the example it is 
onClickRosterDay

Java

```
 //buttons 

    Button rosterMonday;
    Button rosterTuesday;
    Button rosterWednesday;
    Button rosterThursday;
    Button rosterFriday;
    Button rosterSaturday;

    //ArrayList to track button clicks
    private ArrayList<Button> buttonClickedDay;

    in OnCreate

    buttonClickedDay = new ArrayList<>();
    // to start with these are the default clicks. 
    buttonClickedDay.add(rosterMonday ); //previous button clicked
    buttonClickedDay.add(rosterMonday ); // current button clicked



    public void onClickRosterDay(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.rosterMonday:
                    daySelected = "MONDAY";
                    // move current click button to previous button clicked position
                    buttonClickedDay.set(0, buttonClickedDay.get(1)); 
                    // update current clicked position
                    buttonClickedDay.set(1,rosterMonday);
                    break;

                case R.id.rosterTuesday:
                    daySelected = "TUESDAY";
                    buttonClickedDay.set(0, buttonClickedDay.get(1));
                    buttonClickedDay.set(1,rosterTuesday);
                    break;

                case R.id.rosterWednesday:
                    daySelected = "WEDNESDAY";
                    buttonClickedDay.set(0, buttonClickedDay.get(1));
                    buttonClickedDay.set(1,rosterWednesday);
                    break;

                case R.id.rosterThursday:
                    daySelected = "THURSDAY";
                    buttonClickedDay.set(0, buttonClickedDay.get(1));
                    buttonClickedDay.set(1,rosterThursday);
                    break;

                case R.id.rosterFriday:
                    daySelected = "FRIDAY";
                    buttonClickedDay.set(0, buttonClickedDay.get(1));
                    buttonClickedDay.set(1,rosterFriday);
                    break;

                case R.id.rosterSaturday:
                    daySelected = "SATURDAY";
                    buttonClickedDay.set(0, buttonClickedDay.get(1));
                    buttonClickedDay.set(1,rosterSaturday);
                    break;
            }





        if(buttonClickedDay.get(0) != buttonClickedDay.get(1)) {
            // update background color of  previous button clicked    
buttonClickedDay.get(0).setBackgroundColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            // update background color of  current button clicked      
buttonClickedDay.get(1).setBackgroundColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.textBackgroundGreen));
        }
    }
```