# Changing background color of the layout on a button click in Android

Tags: android

I am a newbie in Android. So please spare me if I am asking a stupid question.

My application contains just one button in a Linear Layout. Requirement is, I have to change the background color of the linear layout of my app on a button click. By default it is **WHITE**, when I press on the button it should change to some random color and when I press the button again, it should change to the default color (white) again.

`button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)` (on the **OnClick()** method), changes the background color to **BLUE**, but how to get back to the default color?

Answer (score 3):

create the xml file in **drawble** folder

**change_colcor.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 


<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:color="#222222"  />
 <item
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:color="#4aa5d4"  />
</selector>
```

and then set the XML file to button background

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/mybutton"
android:background="@drawable/change_colcor" />
```

Answer (score 1):

i hope this code will help you! take boolean variable when button is clicked.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  boolean iscolor = true;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

         if(iscolor)
         {
             layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
             iscolor = false;
         }
         else
         {
             layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
             iscolor = true;
         }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Still not working. I think there's some issue in the logic part in the onClick() method. Approach is correct. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Create a shape named `button_pressed.xml` as follows....

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="@color/blue" />

    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="@color/blue" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

</shape>
```

Suppose, you have tow button whose `id`s are `R.id.btn` and `R.id.btn1` as follows...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Press Me 1" />        


</LinearLayout>
```

Write `onClick()` method as follows...which will allow you to retain the changed color until another button pressed.

```
Button button;

public void onClick(View v) {

    Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_pressed);
    dr.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn:

        if (button == null) {
            button = (Button) findViewById(v.getId());
        } else {
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);
            button = (Button) findViewById(v.getId());
        }
        button.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);

        break;        


    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

[Reference from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044788/button-change-background-color-on-click)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But I have just one button on my layout and I have to use that one button only to change the background color to default on a click. Cant put the second button.

Answer (score 0):

This is a completely Java Based approach to your problem. It is as follows;

```
package com.example.param.background_changer;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.util.TypedValue;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



//Head
        //Layout type
        final RelativeLayout myLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

            //Original Background color
            myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);


//Body

            //Button
            final Button Changer_Button = new Button(this);

                //Button Properties
                Changer_Button.setText("Click Here");
                Changer_Button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                    //Position Properties
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ChangerButton_Position_Details =
                                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                                );
                        ChangerButton_Position_Details.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                        ChangerButton_Position_Details.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);

        myLayout.addView(Changer_Button,ChangerButton_Position_Details);

            //On click listener
            Changer_Button.setOnClickListener(
                    new Button.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            Changer_Button.setText("Button Clicked");
                            myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        }
                    }
            );

        setContentView(myLayout);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable bg = new android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable();

bg.setColor(new android.content.res.ColorStateList(new int[][] {{-android.R.attr.state_pressed}, {android.R.attr.state_pressed}},new int[] {Color.parseColor("#901020"), Color.parseColor("#40109020")}));
bg.setShape(1);
bg.setCornerRadius(10);
bg.setStroke(2, new android.content.res.ColorStateList(new int[][] {{-android.R.attr.state_pressed}, {android.R.attr.state_pressed}}, new int[] {Color.parseColor("#505050"), Color.parseColor("#502010")}));

button1.setBackground(bg);
```

Answer (score 0):

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/b1"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.adouble;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b1;
    LinearLayout layout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1=findViewById(R.id.b1);
        layout=findViewById(R.id.ll);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP just asked for a single line of code to get it back to the default color: something similar to `button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)`.  He didn't ask for an entire algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

This code will generate a random color on the background on a button click. By default it is WHITE, when the button is pressed it changes to some random color and when the button is pressed again, it changes to the default color (white) again.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageButton mybutton;
LinearLayout layout;
Boolean color = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mybutton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
    mybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Random ranNum = new Random();
            if (color==false)
            {
                int myNum = Color.argb(255,ranNum.nextInt(256),ranNum.nextInt(256),ranNum.nextInt(256));
                layout.setBackgroundColor(myNum);
                color = true;
            }
            else
            {
                layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                color = false;
            }
        }
    });
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

add below code to your layout

```
android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
```